# Loop to go through each worksheet in workbook

Tags: vba, loops, excel, worksheet

I'm trying to loop through each worksheet in the workbook but it's not working.  I think it's the ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets not recognizing each worksheet and only running on the Active worksheet.  Any suggestions would be great! I'm sure this is a basic fix but can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks!

```
Sub LoopThroughWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet2") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet8") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet42") Then

            With ws
                'code
                'Sheets("Formula").Select
                Range("FormulaRow").Copy
                'Selection.Copy
                ActiveSheet.Select
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Calculate
                Range("Q1:X1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Range("Q3:X3000").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Calculate
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False

            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: "I think it's the ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets not recognizing each worksheet":  It's good to have a theory which might account for the problem.  Why not add some code to your loop to show whether or not what's the ActiveSheet is actually changing on each iteration?

Comment: I can see that it's not changing on each iteration which is why I was thinking that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `With` statement, you need to proceed each time you wish to reference that object with a `.` to use it the way you're intending.
But, if I understand your intnent, I think the easiest solution would be to add in this line of code:

```
ws.Select
```

as follows:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet2") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet8") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet42") Then

       ws.Select

        With ws
            'code
            'Sheets("Formula").Select
            Range("FormulaRow").Copy

        ...
```

and then you should also work on changing things such as from `Range("FormulaRow").Copy` to `.Range("FormulaRow").Copy` so you're sure to be using the `With` statement correctly.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Oh yes, that is coming back to me. Unfortunately FormulaRow is on a different tab and trying to copy from not the ws tab is tripping me up.

Comment: With adding the ws.Select, it's not skipping the sheets I don't wan to perform the action on.

Comment: It definitely looks like you never Activated any sheets, so the original ActiveSheet remains the same even though you are looping through the WS Array in the background.
You might want to get out of .Select, .Copy, .Paste in your code, and just set values directly.  It makes more work and looks sloppy with all the screens flashing around in the background activating.  Just make statements.
Sheets(sheetname).Cells(iRow, iCol) = VALUE YOU WANT TO SET
Then you can use iRow and iCol as variables, and perform all kinds of conditional checks and Loops.  Instead of the ONE way the macro recorded.

Comment: If the formula row is on a different sheet.  Specify it.

Sheets("FormulaSheet").Range("FormulaRow")